# Source for candle lighting on Rosh Chodesh

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, rosh-chodesh-new-month

Can I have a source for where does it says that one can/should light candles on erev rosh chodesh?
Or is it only on rosh chodesh tevet, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely referring to this custom mentioned by [R. Joseph Hayyim of Baghdad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Hayyim):

**[Ben Ish Chai Parshat Vayeishev Hilchot Chanukah # 28](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14054&st=&pgnum=49&hilite=)**

> ומנהגינו להדליק שמן למאור לכבוד נשמת רבי מאיר בעל הנס זיע"א ביום ר"ח
>   טבת
>
> And our custom is to kindle oil for a light in honor of the soul of
>   Rabbi Meir the Master of the Miracle (may his merit protect us, amen)
>   on the day of Rosh Chodesh Tevet.

Comment: Can you edit in the reason for that date? Is this date his *yahrtzeit*?

Comment: @DanF It doesn't say the reason.